# update postgre dando errado

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

Segue o código:

```
def update_table(file_name, id, column1, column2):
    conn = connect()
    c = conn.cursor()

    today = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime('%Y/%m/%d/'))

    query = f"""UPDATE "IMPRESSAO" SET "{column1}" = %s, "{column2}" = %s
                       WHERE "NUM_IMPRESSAO" LIKE '%{id}';"""
    print(query, "\n")
    data = (file_name, today)

    try:
        c.execute(query, data)
        conn.commit()
        count = c.rowcount
        print(f"\033[1;32;m {count} Record(s) inserted successfully")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"\033[1;31;m update_table error: {e}")

    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
```

O que há de errado com ele? apresenta o seguinte erro:

> tuple index out of range

Sou nova no postgre, então posso ter feito muita coisa errada... Desde já, obrigada.

Comment: E o qual a saída de print(query, "\n")? Não está faltando nada na atribuição anterior?

Comment: sai isso: UPDATE "IMPRESSAO" SET "BINARY" = %s, "DATA_ENVIO_BINARY" = %s  WHERE "NUM_IMPRESSAO" LIKE '%08918';

Comment: Tente trocar '%Y/%m/%d/' por '%Y-%m-%d' (data no formato ISO).

Comment: Essa mensagem parece ser referente ao python. Na saída no terminal a mensagem de erro não indica qual linha está gerando o erro? Seria interessante você adicionar mais informações na pergunta.